# Randomly Generate Streeview Point without GIS in country

Tags: google-maps, javascript, geoserver

I'm interested in pulling street view data at random within a country.

I can only figure out how to generate a point within a bounding box. Often it pulls data from nearby nations. I'm using a GIS server right now, but I'm interested in removing it from the workflow since it's a pain.

Anybody know of any javascript mapping API that can randomly generate a point within a complex polygon, such as a country boundary?

Comment: Is the Geoserver tag correct here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"Random Google Street View. Teleport to a random point on the globe. Filter by country or continent. Share weird and wonderful places with your friends. Now with Antarctica, Brazil"*

http://www.mapcrunch.com/

featured recently on 
http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2010/10/random-google-maps.html

Comment: Thanks, I was already using an algorithm, that is mostly identical.  Just trying to see if there was a faster way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice javascript implementation of the Ray casting algorithm on [CloudDev](http://www.cdev.org/node/60)

Using this it should be quite easy to:

```
//pseudocode
do 
  {create pt as a random point within the envelope}
until (pt is in poly)
```

An alternative approach if you are working with Google Maps might be the PointInPolygon test from [AppDelegate](http://appdelegateinc.com/blog/2010/05/16/point-in-polygon-checking/)